# Is there a way for a Battle Master to swap out maneuvers without taking more fighter levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, combat-maneuver, battle-master

I currently have an Ancestral Guardian barbarian 8 / Battle Master fighter 3. Some of the maneuvers I selected earlier in this character's career aren't working out as well in Tier 3. Battle Master provides one option for swapping them out (PHB, p. 73):

> ***Maneuvers.*** You learn three maneuvers of your choice [...]
>
> You learn two additional maneuvers of your choice at 7th, 10th, and 15th level. Each time you learn new maneuvers, you can also replace one maneuver you know with a different one.

Unfortunately, that would require me to take 4 more levels of fighter, including a dead level at fighter 5. I do not want to advance beyond level 4 in fighter; taking barbarian all the way to level 17 would be even better. **Is there a way to swap out maneuvers without taking fighter to level 7?**

Comment: Does anyone know if there are balance reasons to prevent re-training choices for multiclassed characters, as long as it was slow? If not, I would certainly want house rule a way for characters to do it, as long as they didn't do it too often (ideally in place of retraining something in their new class if that fits, or in place of some other small bonus)

Comment: @JackV. Sounds like the beginnings of a new question. If you come up with an example rule, people could evaluate it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Take the Martial Adept feat

The key is in the wording of the feat and the Battle Master maneuvers section. The first bullet of [Martial Adept](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/martial-adept) says (PHB, p. 168, emphasis mine):

> **You learn** two maneuvers of your choice from among those available to the Battle Master archetype in the fighter class. [...]

The second paragraph of the [Battle Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster) maneuvers section, quoted in the question, says (PHB, p. 73, emphasis mine):

> You learn two additional maneuvers of your choice at 7th, 10th, and 15th level. Each time **you learn** new maneuvers, you can also replace one maneuver you know with a different one.

Since Martial Adept lets you **learn** additional maneuvers, the Battle Master feature allows you to switch one of your previously-selected maneuvers with another one. The feat also grants two additional maneuvers and one additional superiority die. No additional fighter levels required.

Comment: After I realized you were answering your own question, it confused me for a moment that your self-answer addresses yourself as "you" (i.e. "you quoted") :P

Comment: @V2Blast Hah! Are self-answers usually in 1st person or 2nd person?

Comment: Haha. I dunno about usually, but I'd personally either use first person or simply avoid the problem by changing it to "The second paragraph of the Battle Master maneuvers section, quoted in the question, says".